# How to read XML elements using jquery in HTML

Tags: jquery, xml

I am trying to read XML elements without using elements name i.e. "Books" from the following example. for e.g.

```
  <Books>
           <book>
              <title>C++</title>
              <author>A</author>
           </book>
           <book>
              <title>XML</title>
              <author>X</author>
           </book>
    </Books>
```

In other words How to dynamically read "Books" element and assign children element to array using jquery in HTML. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: have you looked at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ ?

Comment: Hello Lakhae, try this http://killertilapia.blogspot.in/2011/03/using-jquery-to-read-external-xml-file.html

Comment: Thank you Naveen. I can read the xml file by using $(this).find('text').text(); Now what I am trying to do is without giving 'text' how can I read all the sub elements of <Formdata> and assign them to array.

Comment: You can't. You can't select something from nothing? You can use  `children()`, `closest()`, `first()`, `last()`, `next()` and a hundred other methods without using the tagname, but you can't get all tags with a certain name unless you select them by name, or if they are all children of the same element etc.

Comment: Thanks adeneo. How can I get all children element if I have one parent element only.

Comment: `$('Books').children();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. I have found my solution

```
var xml = "<root><stuff></stuff><stuff><stuffchild></stuffchild></stuff></root>";

function alertit(jqueryObject) {
    if (jqueryObject.length === 0) return;

    jqueryObject.each(function() {
        alert(this.nodeName.toLowerCase());
    });

    alertit(jqueryObject.children());
}

alertit($(xml));

http://jsfiddle.net/TBwm8/3/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote simple HTML for you. Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/UC2dM/185/

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/echo/xml/',
    data: {xml:'<Books><book><title>C++</title><author>A</author> </book><book><title>XML</title><author>X</author></book></Books>'},
    dataType: 'xml',
    type:'post',
    success: function(data){
        var xml = $(data);
        $('#container').append( CategoryToUl(xml.children()) );
    }
});

function CategoryToUl(xml){
    var categories = xml.children('book');
    if (categories.length > 0)
    {
        var ul = $('<ul/>');
        categories.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var li = $('<li/>');
            var a = $('<a/>',{
                text: $this.children('title').text()
            });
            li.append(a);
            li.append( CategoryToUl( $this ) );
            ul.append(li);
        });
        return ul;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I am looking for.